# Hover Link Colour, CSS

Tags: html, css

Right now, I've implemented legal notices at the bottom of my page and I've managed to make all the links white.  However, I want only the hover colour to be different, like this website: http://www.condolicious.com/

Can someone please tell me how to do this?  I tried changing the a:hover color thing and I'm only getting solid colours.  Thanks.

```
#footer .notice a {
    a:link; color: #fff;
    a:visited; color: #fff;
    a:hover; color: #fff;
    a:active; color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your :hover styles need to be separate CSS declarations - not part of the `#footer .notice a {}` block, like so:

```
#footer .notice a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer .notice a:hover,
#footer .notice a:active {
    color:#CC0000;/*Whatever color you like */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this

```
#footer .notice a { 
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer .notice a:hover { 
    color: #fff;  // change to a different color
}
```

Same with `:visited` and `:active`.

Comment: The second text-decoration rule is not needed - it's covered by the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Did you realize all your links have the same color? Even the hover state?

```
#footer .notice a:hover { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to adjust your syntax

```
#footer .notice a:hover {
    color:green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax above isn't going to work:

```
#footer .notice a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer .notice a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

The first CSS declaration will set the colour of all your `a` tags (you don't need to set them individually unless they're styled differently). The second sets the colour on hover, a pseudoclass that is supported by all modern browsers (and most older ones).

You don't need to set the text-decoration again in the second declaration, as the `:hover` already inherits all the "generic" attributes set in the first declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to declare each link hover state separately, like this:

```
/* you can combine css declarations as follows */
#footer .notice a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer .notice a:visited {
    color: #fff; /* change this to whatever color you'd like */
}

#footer .notice a:hover {
    color: #000; /* change this to whatever color you'd like */
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#footer .notice a:active {
    color: #fff; /* change this to whatever color you'd like */
}
```

Comment: Why would you make your visited links the same colour as non-visited links?

Comment: I wouldn't. I left it in there as a placeholder in case the OP wants to style it separately, given that he included it in his original set of css declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
   #footer .notice a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    #footer .notice a:hover {
    color:#AAA
    }
```

here, #AAA is color when anchor tag is hovered.

edit: removed the invalid css

Comment: This CSS isn't valid - there are still selectors inside the declaration block (you can't put a:link inside another block, etc.)